# Could I have some advice on basic Asynchronous Socket Programming in C#?

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I've developing (or trying to, anyway) a program that uses Asynchronous Socket to, supposedly, pass strings to and fro the server and client, at any time.

This program requires no more than one client be connected to a server. I tried Socket Programming, but I found out it blocks the program until either one receives something.

Since I have only a basic understanding of Asynchronous socket programming, I just went for the simplest one I could find, or at least, the simplest one I could understand.

Here's my code for the Server:

```
    public Socket g_server_conn;
    public byte[] g_bmsg;
    public bool check = false;  

    private void net_As_Accept(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket server_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        g_server_conn = server_conn.EndAccept(iar);
        g_bmsg = new byte[1024];
        check = true;
        g_server_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Receive), g_server_conn);
    }

    private void net_As_Send(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket server_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        server_conn.EndSend(iar);
    }

    private void net_As_Receive(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket server_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            server_conn.EndReceive(iar);
            if (g_bmsg.Length != 0)
            {
                net_Data_Receive(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length));
                check = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "GG");
        }
    }

    public void net_Data_Send(string msg2snd) // Function for sending through socket
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg2snd);
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg2snd);
        g_server_conn.BeginSend(byData, 0, byData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Send), g_server_conn);
        g_server_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Receive), g_server_conn);
    }

    private void net_Data_Receive(string txt)
    {
        if (lblBuffer.InvokeRequired)
            lblBuffer.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { net_Data_Receive(txt); }));
        else
            lblBuffer.Text = txt;

        if (txt.StartsWith("&"))
        {
            // Do something              
        }
    }
```

And here's my code for the Client:

```
    private void net_As_Connect(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
                Socket client_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
                client_conn.EndConnect(iar);
                g_bmsg = new byte[1024];
                check = true;
                string toSendData = "&" + net_Name;
                net_Data_Send(toSendData);
                g_client_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Receive), g_client_conn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "GG");
        }
    }

    private void net_As_Send(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket client_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        client_conn.EndSend(iar);
    }

    private void net_As_Receive(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        if (g_bmsg.Length != 0)
        {
            net_Data_Receive(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length));
            check = false;
        }
    }

    public void net_Data_Send(string msg2snd)
    {
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg2snd);

        g_client_conn.BeginSend(byData, 0, byData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Send), g_client_conn);
        g_client_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Receive), g_client_conn);
    }

    private void net_Data_Receive(string txt)
    {
        if (lblBuffer.InvokeRequired)
            lblBuffer.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { net_Data_Receive(txt); }));
        else
            lblBuffer.Text = txt;

        if (txt.StartsWith("&"))
        {
            // Do Something              
        }
        else if (txt.StartsWith("$"))
        {
            // Do something Else
        }

    }
```

Now, the Client can connect to the Server fine. The Client can even send in a string containing the user's name to the Server, which will then be displayed on the Server. The Server then sends out the name of its user to the Client, which the client receives and displays. Whatever is sent is stored in a Label (lblBuffer)

But afterwards, say I have the following code:

```
    private void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string posMov = "Stuff to send";
        net_Data_Send(posMov);
    }
```

The Client receives nothing. Putting a Message Box in net_Data_Send(msg2snd) function reveals that the server does in fact send out the message. In fact, putting in the Message Box in that function makes it work (the Client receives it), for reasons I don't know. Since I haven't tried sending a message from the Client to the Server (other than the name when the Client Connects), I assume the Client will have the same problem sending to the Server.

Also, when it does send the second message (by putting a Message Box in the net_Data_Send function), only parts of the Label (lblBuffer) are overwritten. So if I my name is "Anon E. Moose", and the Server sends that when the Client connects, and I try to send out, say, "0.0" (via button press) the Label on the Client would then read "0.0n E. Moose".

What did I do wrong? Can I have some help on this, please?

Perhaps I have a problem with net_Data_Receive and net_Data_Send?

Comment: The problem you have with the overwriting is that you are converting the contents of the buffer from ascii bytes to a string, g_bmsg.Length will return the length of the byte array, not the current length of the data that was placed in it by the receive call. You need to store how many actual bytes are read, and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call BeginReceive on your client again, it looks like you are only calling it once, so after it has received the server name, it isn't listening for any more data from the server

```
private void net_As_Receive(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    var bytesRead = g_client_conn.EndReceive(iar);


    if (bytesRead != 0)
    {
        net_Data_Receive(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, bytesRead));
        check = false;
    }

    g_client_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Receive), g_client_conn);
}
```

also, as I mentioned in my comment, use the bytesRead value to work out how much of the buffer you need to use.

You will need to work out if the data you have received from the socket is the full amount, or if you need to read more data to make up the current message from the other side.

Comment: Thanks. It can now receive the messages. Although I'm still working on the label overwrite thing. By the way, there's no 'var' in my C#. I think it's only available in C# 3.0. Would changing that to 'int' mess up anything?

Comment: nope use int :) sorry, so used to using var now it's 2nd nature!

Answer (score 1):

BeginReceive doesn't just call its callback whenever a new packet (string in your case arrives). In fact. BeginReceive or any raw socket method works in a stream based fasion, not packet based. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx for an example.

What you need to do, is in your 'net_As_Receive' callback method (naming is terrible imo), you need to make a call first to socket.EndRecieve(IAsyncResult), which in turn returns the total bytes currently available. After that, you have to make a decision whether to receive more data or not.

For example:

```
private StringBuilder packetBuilder;
{ 
    if (packetBuilder == null)
        packetBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // finalyze the receive
    int length = g_server_conn.EndReceive(iar);

    if (length != 0) 
    { 
        // get the total bytes received. Note that the length property is of that of the number of bytes received rather than that of the buffer
        packetBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(g_bmsg, 0, length));

        net_Data_Receive(packetBuilder.ToString()); 
        check = false; 
    } 

    // receive the next part
    g_server_conn.BeginReceive(g_bmsg, 0, g_bmsg.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(net_As_Receive), g_server_conn);  
}
```

Note that this example doesnt care about packages. It will work if your lucky but there is a good change either a part of a string will be shown or 2 different strings will be combined. A good implementation will look for a string end and only show that part while buffering the rest untill a new string end is found. You can also use a StreamReader for making your life much easier